# Bind Custom Attached Property in Code or Styles/Templates

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this WPF that is repeated through the form:

```
<WrapPanel local:RadioChecker.IsChecked="False">
    <RadioButton Content="Yes" Height="16" GroupName = "rbgSeizure" Name="rbSeizureYes" 
                    local:RadioChecker.IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" />
    <RadioButton Content="No"  Height="16" GroupName = "rbgSeizure" Name="rbSeizureNo" 
                    local:RadioChecker.IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

**What is the way to go about setting each WrapPanel as above and each RadioButton in the same manner without having to copy and paste the above `local:...` onto each control?**

I can get each type control in the code behind like:

```
GetLogicalChildCollection<RadioButton>(mainPanel)
    .ForEach(rb =>
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        //binding.Source
    });
```

But I'm not sure how to set the binding's / attach the custom attached property to the controls.

Comment: One way might be to derive MyRadioButtonWithCustomAttachedProperty from RadioButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
GetLogicalChildCollection<RadioButton>(mainPanel).ForEach(
    rb =>
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty),
            Source = rb
        };               
        rb.SetBinding(RadioChecker.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
    });
```

or this:

```
GetLogicalChildCollection<RadioButton>(mainPanel).ForEach(
    rb => rb.SetBinding(RadioChecker.IsCheckedProperty,
                        new Binding("IsChecked") { Source = rb }));
```